# android Adding Account with AccountManager, No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS (has extras) }

Tags: android, android-intent, accountmanager

in some phones (in a certain "oneplus" android v6.0.1 to be exact) . I'm getting `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS (has extras) }`  error when I try to call up the account add screen with what seemed to be the "right" way.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);
 intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[]{Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE});
 startActivity(intent);
```

I can seemingly add

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS" />
</intent-filter>
```

to my login activity, but should I even do that? if so why is it working on most phones but crashing on one. I want my account intent to go through as if the user is trying to create an account through the phone's settings screen and this seems like a bad shortcut.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding so have patience. This popup sounds like two manifest filters matching an Implicit intent ie. same action, catagory... possible cause two versions of the same app installed at the same time? two matching filters in the same manifest etc.

Comment: how does the phones settings have an icon for your accounttype if you did not implement it?

Comment: I've implemented the account and it does indeed appear in phone's settings where you can create a new account, that is for most phones. but that particular android v6 phone seems to be different for whatever reason. which is why I am confused

Comment: You refer to a picker, so apparently you implemented the create account stuff twice and you are asked which one to use. For example suppose you have a link on a page somewhere and you click on it and it says which browser do you want to use, same idea. Now do you have two filters in the manifest or two versions of the app installed? Why does it ask you to pick if you have only one choice?

Comment: that's exactly what I mean. the system was working as expected on most phones, however that one phone seem to not recognize the default phone settings as a receiver of my intent. thus it throws an exception saying there is no activity to handle it. if I add my own login activity as a receiver then I have two receivers on other phones that worked before this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. apparently the phone which I addressed was running on a cyanogen and for whatever reason where other android 6 phones (and emulator) did not require GET_ACCOUNT permission for a request for my own application's account, this phone did.

the error says nothing about lacking permission however after acquiring GET_ACCOUNT with run-time request, it functions as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Four things](https://github.com/Udinic/AccountAuthenticator) are needed to set up the Custom accounts in android. Implement Abstractaccountauthenticator to expose methods to add accounts etc. Extend AccountAuthenticatorActivity the view part of the deal. In the android manifest  a refrence to an xml resource file that itself refers to icons, string labels and the xml resource file.

Now I suspect you are using a pre-existing account type, google perhaps, that works on most phones. Everything android has gmail or googleplay store. some google app. So the big question is what is the value of Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE in your code and do you want to make your own custom account type?

Comment: no actually, I'm using my own app's account type and I already followed those steps. I have my loginActivity extend AccountAuthenticatorActivity but did not specify any filters for it in manifest, as I think it shouldn't go directly to this activity but through setting's

Comment: Just try manifest filters and you will find it listed in the settings

Comment: I know manifest filter solves this exception as I stated. however it just feels like a hack. on phones that didn't throw exception before one gets a selection popup asking if one wants to choose my own login activity or phone's account settings. if mine is chosen the intent no longer goes through my 'AccountAuthenticator''s 'addAccount' method and is delivered plain.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding so have patience. This popup sounds like two manifest filters matching an Implicit intent ie. same action, catagory... possible cause two versions of the same app installed at the same time? two matching filters in the same manifest etc.